# How to revert liquid to it's original state

Tags: mesh, faces, fluid-simulation

[image]

I applied fluid physics to this mesh, then decided to take them off, I delete/disabled them, however the mesh now has invisible faces and I can't figure out how to make them visible again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I you add fluid domain, it often switches the viewport shading to Wireframe mode.   Also, did you delete the Fluid Domain object?  FD object adds a mesh (that is in wireframe mode) that will also have surface Material added.